# Problem running SVN copy from Batch file FOR loop

Tags: svn, dos, command-prompt, batch-file

I have a loop in a .BAT file which does the following, as a quick hack to let me branch projects (input checking, etc left out, this is the command which gets run):

```
@for %%X in (%~3) do svn copy ^
 https://my.svn.account/%%X/trunk ^
 "https://my.svn.account/%%X/branches/%~1" ^
 -m "%~2"
```

So you use it like:

> branchTool test_branch "testing branch tool" "proj1,proj2"

The SVN commands *look* right:

```
>branchTool.bat test_branch "testing branch tool" "proj1,proj2"
svn copy  https://my.svn.account/proj1/trunk  "https://my.svn.account/proj1/branches/test_branch"  -m "testing branch tool"
svn copy  https://my.svn.account/proj2/trunk  "https://my.svn.account/proj2/branches/test_branch"  -m "testing branch tool"
```

However SVN isn't actually running - the .bat file just loops through quickly printing the commands, and nothing happens.

**If I copy-paste the output from each line written to the console and run them individually, they work as expected**

*Comments on using ugly DOS hacking scripts aside*, what's the bug? It fails the same with even one input project name, e.g running:

> branchTool test_branch "testing branch
>   tool" proj1

Comment: try to use only one line, because the caret do a multiline AND escapes the first character of the next line

Comment: jeb: correct but note the spaces - and the fact copy-pasting the output works fine. I don't get SVN complaining of bad commands either... I just get _nothing_. I _will_ test this though in case something else weird is happening.

Comment: That the output works is different from the result of multiline escapes, because there are escaped spaces. What do you get, if you replace "SVN" with "echo"? And what do you see if you activate "echo on"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming its something to do with your use of the caret character.  I've always avoided using it - but can't remember the reason why ....

I'd suggest trying braces instead.  E.g.:

```
@for %%X in (%~3) do (
    svn copy https://my.svn.account/%%X/trunk "https://my.svn.account/%%X/branches/%~1" -m "%~2"
)
```

You could also break the command apart for better legiblity/maintainabilty.  I've always prefered assigning numbered parameters to named environment variables.  You can then make the intent of the parameters obvious to a later reader of your script.  (I usually wrap any environment variable usage in a startlocal/endlocal pair to ensure I don't pollute the callers environment with my temporary variables.  E.g.:

```
setlocal
for %%X in (%~3) do (
  set SRC=https://my.svn.account/%%X/trunk
  set DST=https://my.svn.account/%%X/branches/%~1
  svn copy "%SRC%" "%DST" -m "%~2"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: But it doesn't explain why your variant fails. Does your multiple line variant run in braces?

Answer (score -1):

You might try specifying the fully qualified path to the svn executable, for example C:\path\to\Subversion\svn.exe.  It could be that the svn executable is not on environment's path when you execute the batch script.

Comment: No, already tested it - and also then I would get an error rather than nothing happening.